# Share location in service-agnostic way

Tags: location

I want to send by email the event location (location name + address with exact latitude / longitude). I know the full address and the exact lat/long values. 
I could send out:

1. A google maps link (https://goo.gl/maps/8qbWJB44Gt42)
2. OSM link (http://osm.org/go/0BOdUm3V1--)
3. Geo URI : (geo:48.85812,2.29381?z=18)

The problem is that the first two work fine on desktops and most (in my experience) phones with an active data connection, since they depend on a web based service (Google Maps and OSM respectively). The geo: method is service independent - the location is completely encoded.
However, desktop browsers don't handle it.

So the question is: what is currently the best way to share location when the target audience can be on desktop or mobile.

Comment: Not sure we're the best audience to answer this. Sounds like an implementation about what the best cross-device solution is for map display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which is very simle and works fine in any case, is:

[image]

**Eiffel Tower** [**(see on map)**](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower,+5+Avenue+Anatole+France,+75007+Paris,+France/@48.8584131,2.2920251,16.5z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x47e66fe1f3bfb4ad:0x7bd31375becf28cd!2sEiffel+Tower,+5+Avenue+Anatole+France,+75007+Paris,+France!3b1!3m1!1s0x47e66fe1f3bfb4ad:0x7bd31375becf28cd)
5 Avenue Anatole France
75007 Paris
France

Provide:

- An address
- A link to the map
- An map fragment as an image
- If they really need and know how to cope with `lat/lon`, you can add these, too (for most users these mean nothing)

Comment: Accepting your solution, because it solves the problem for the most part. I am not including the map thumbnail image, instead  three lines as you have written with geo: URI at the end.

Comment: I came across this site, which is how Wikimedia sites handles locations: https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Eiffel_Tower&params=48_51_29.6_N_2_17_40.2_E_type:landmark_region:FR-75